# Laravel sanctum $request->validate not return json when validation fails

Tags: laravel

This is the first time i use Sanctum/Jetstream it and i can't understand why, during an incorrect validation `$request->validate` the message about validation errors in the JSON format does not come to response, but simply shows the main page. Debug mode is enabled, there are no errors in the laravel logs too. I use this example code from the official documentation, but the validation does not response JSON errors, but if the credentials I am sending are correct, i get the correct token.

```
Route::post('/sanctum/token', function (Request $request) {

    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'device_name' => 'required',
    ]);


    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();



    if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        ]);
    }

    return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you add `Accept: application/json` in the header?

Comment: I used insomnia  http client, why it doesn’t work by default with `Accept: application/json`, I don’t know, thanks, added and it worked!

Comment: anytime dude... Happy Coding :)